# Cериализация объекта. Java

Tags: java, serializable

Всем привет!

Есть ли способ при сериализации объекта обойти полное совпадение/повторение пути? Например:

на стороне клиента -

```
com.example.myProjectOne.model.MyClass
```

на стороне сервера -

```
com.example.notMyProject.entity.MyClass
```

получаю -

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.example.myProjectOne.model.MyClass

при полном совпадении имен пакетов все работает...

Comment: сериализуйте в json или другой формат

Comment: @Artem Konovalov та я бы и за, но не положено... приходится создавать библиотеку объектов для клиента и сервера, что вызывает в свою очередь неудобства

Comment: а дублировать код на клиенте и сервере удобно? а если состав полей разойдется?